# How do you increment a value while transforming STR in INT?

Tags: sql, operation

I use 2 tables "population" and "sous_nutrition" as I want to calculate the ratio of underfed (under_nutrition) people / countries.

'population' table has a 'year' column which displays INT values:

[image: population table]

'sous_nutrition' has 3 years ranges:

[image: sous_nutrition table]

So to match them, I do an operation to remove the 2nd year mentioned, the dash, and transform it all into INTEGER:

```
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(sous_nutrition.year,6,4) AS INTEGER) = population.year
```

This way I get an unique INT I can match but that would be the first year. As an example:

in 2011-2013, I am keeping the 2011 value.

So, I would like keep the value that would be in the middle (2012 in our example) and  increment the result by +1.

How would you do this?

Here is the actual code:

```sql
SELECT sous_nutrition.country, 
                sous_nutrition.nb_persons_avg_3y / population.population as nutrition_ratio,
                population.year
FROM sous_nutrition, population
WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(sous_nutrition.year,6,4) AS INTEGER) = population.year 
  AND sous_nutrition.country = population.country 
ORDER BY nutrition_ratio DESC
```

Comment: Your logic returns the last year, not the first. Simply increment or decrement *after* the cast: `CAST(SUBSTR(sous_nutrition.year,6,4) AS INTEGER) -1`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve and why. You say you are keeping 2011 in your example but the code says 2013 and for the math why not just add (or subtract) 1? Maybe you could explain why you want to match a row in population to a specific row in sous_nutrition since I see multiple matches

Comment: Your tables were fine, please roll back the tables as images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just take the beginning of the range and add one year:

```
SELECT n.country, 
       ( n.nb_persons_avg_3y / p.population) as nutrition_ratio,
       p.year
FROM sous_nutrition n JOIN
     population p
     ON n.country = p.country AND
        CAST(SUBSTR(sous_nutrition.year, 1, 4) AS INTEGER) + 1 = p.year
ORDER BY nutrition_ratio DESC
```